# POST to server only posts field names and not user responses PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I've created a simple form and some PHP to handle it and write to the server:

```html
<div class="main">
<div class= "formholder">
<form action="phone.php" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder= "First Name:" name="forename" required><br>
<input type="text" placeholder= "Last Name:" name="surname" required><br>
<input type="text" maxlength="12" placeholder="Phone Number: +44" name="phone" required><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

The PHP I'm using is as follows:

```
    <?php
$forename = $_POST["forename"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$text = "NAME: $forename    $surname <br>
 PHONE: $phone<br>";
 $file = fopen("./data/responses.html","a+");
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Whenever a response is submitted the server adds the field names to the `responses.html` document, but not the data that the user submitted.

The result in the file is;

```html
NAME:      <br>
 PHONE: <br>
```

It adds the fields each time, just not the user inputs. Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

```
EDIT 1, NEWLINES
```

I'm trying to make it so that after each response the code starts a new line. I've tried this;

```
 <?php
 $file = fopen("./data/responses.html","a+ /n");
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

Currently the response doc looks like this:

```html
<!--Phone Number Responses-->NAME: Name1 Name1 <br>PHONE: Phone1 <!--Next Person:--><br>NAME: Name2 Name2 <br>PHONE: Name2 <!--Next Person:--><br>
```

But I'd prefer a new line started for each response;

```html
<!--Phone Number Responses-->
NAME: Name1 Name1 <br>PHONE: Phone1 <!--Next Person:--><br>
NAME: Name2 Name2 <br>PHONE: Name2 <!--Next Person:--><br>
```

And so on. I added the `<!--Next Person:-->` comment to differentiate because they all save to the same line.

Comment: Your form is using `GET` while you're trying to fetch the data using `$_POST`. Change your form to `method="post"`. A good idea is to turn `display_errors` on in your local PHP environment. Read more here: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display). If you do that, you should get some _"undefined index"_-warnings in your PHP.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you're right, I'm sorry. Flag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below written code:

```
$forename = $_POST["forename"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$text = "NAME: ".$forename." ".$surname." <br>PHONE: ".$phone."<br>";
```

As **Magnus Eriksson** said in his comment that to change:

```
<form action="phone.php" method="get">
```

to

```
<form action="phone.php" method="post">
```

Comment: The concatenation in the OP's question is fine. The variables are inside a double quoted string so they will resolve properly. The issue is that the OP is using the wrong method.

Comment: You should also remove the part about the concatenation (since the OP's version is correct): https://3v4l.org/4kabN

Comment: Any ideas on how to have all responses to go a new line within the code, something like `"\n"` maybe?

Comment: can you explain or show a sample, its not clear for me. `\n` can be used for newline.

Comment: If you need a new blank line use a `\n` or if you need a new line text as `<!-- new contact -->` then, you have to add it in concating as `PHONE: ".$phone."\n <!-- new contact --> \n";`

Comment: I have it as `$text = "<strong>NAME:</strong> ".$forename." ".$surname."    <strong>PHONE:</strong> ".$phone."\n" <br>";` but it doesn't go to the next line?

Comment: Nevermind, got it. `".$phone."\n`, had an extra `"`. Thank You :)

Comment: @Sinto. If on the `responses.php` page I wanted to echo part of the submission how would that work? I'd need to find a way of using `uswords` to capitalise the user's name. `<p>Thank you, <? php echo $forename; ?>for your submission</p>`. The text shows but the user's name is not echoed?

Comment: In HTML: `<p>Thank you, <?=ucfirst($forename); ?>for your submission</p>` In PHP: `echo "<p>Thank you, ". ucfirst($forename)." for your submission</p>";`

Comment: `<?=` is a short code for `<?php echo`. You might be missed it because you added a space b/w `<?` & `php`.